# update sqlite table through attach db very slow

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I have an main sqlite-database ( lots of data ) and a update sqlite-database on my android device. ( data I like to update ).
I would like to update a table in main-db with the data of the table ( same structure ) in update-db with my android app. 
- Means delete all rows in main which exists in the update.
- insert all from update to main.

My approach so far is:

```
 attach db 'path to update' updatedb
 delete from mytable where id in ( select id from updatedb.mytable )
 insert into mytable select * from mytable
```

delete and insert are very slow ( in my opinion ). 
Is there a way to do this faster ?

Comment: Is the main db located on a server?

Comment: no both db's are files in a folder of the android device.

Comment: Why dont you try Batch Insert?..It would greatly lessen the insert time..

Comment: What is the performance and what performance you expect?

Comment: It takes 1-2 minutes to delete and 1-2 minutes to insert. My app downloads the updatedb to the device from a server and updates as described. (5% of the maindb size). Its a bit faster then downloading the hole updated main-db. And I guess that this should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use Batch insert for inserting Large amount of data. Here is the code:

**In your databaseHelper:**

```
public void batchInsert(String sql, ArrayList<String[]> values) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();

    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        String[] record = values.get(i);

        for (int ii = 0; ii < record.length; ii++) {
            stmt.bindString(ii + 1, record[ii]);
        }

        stmt.execute();
        stmt.clearBindings();
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    db.close();
}
```

**In your Activity:**

```
ArrayList<String[]> dataBatch = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        int x = 0;
        for (Data data : dataList) {


            String[] dataArray = { data.getData1(),data.getData2(),data.getData2() };

            dataBatch.add(questionsArray);              

        }

String sql = "INSERT INTO data ";
        sql += "(data1, data2, data3) ";
        sql += "VALUES (?,?,?)";

        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        dbhelper.batchInsert(sql, dataBatch);
```

Basically your execution for databaseHelper may be different. But thats how to Batch insert large number of data.

Comment: Thank you. I can try that. But I have some concerns. I already tried to fetch the data from my updatedb row by row and insert them into my maindb within a transaction. That was slower then "select into select from". I guess this is, what databasehelper does at the end ?

Comment: Yes you should expect it to be slower because you are doing it row by row(Multiple queries). Batch insert, inserts multiple records into MySQL with a single query. So you should expect it to be faster.

On the other hand.. databasehelper is just a single class which has functions for database operations. query, update, delete, batchinsert etc. It depends on your algorithm.

Comment: I am not doing it row by row as you can see in my question. I only mentioned that I also (additionally) tested this row by row, which I expected to be the same behaviour like databaseHelper. So I am wondering if I get really a better performance, because my statemant is also a single query.